# DynamoDB: describeTable request fails with NSException / DBResourceNotFoundException

Tags: amazon-web-services, runtime-error, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to wrap my head around DynamoDB calls through the AWS SDK for iOS7. For getting the security token I us the provided Security Token Service (STS). All goes pretty well, including the responded security token, until I want to request my DynamoDB for table description, thus making a request.

```
// create the client
AmazonDynamoDBClient *ddb = [[AmazonDynamoDBClient alloc] retain];
// create the Provider (using STS)
AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient *sts = [[AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient alloc]
    initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];
AmazonSTSCredentialsProvider *provider = [[AmazonSTSCredentialsProvider alloc]
    initWithClient:sts];

[ddb initWithCredentialsProvider:provider];

[ddb setEndpoint:ddbendpoint];

AmazonCredentials *credentials = [provider credentials];

DynamoDBDescribeTableRequest *dtreq = [[[DynamoDBDescribeTableRequest alloc]
    initWithTableName:@"userdata"] autorelease]; // Table userdata is ACTIVE

[dtreq setRequestEndpoint:ddbendpoint]; // EU_WEST_1
[dtreq setCredentials:credentials];

@try {
    DynamoDBDescribeTableResponse *dtres = [[AmazonClientManager ddb]
        describeTable:dtreq]; // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
}
@catch (DynamoDBResourceNotFoundException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"%@",exception.errorCode);
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
2013-11-22 13:37:59.621 myApp[3041:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
   exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString
   substringFromIndex:]: Index 2147483650 out of bounds; string length 32'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x01c035e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x019868b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x01c033bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
3   Foundation                          0x015ab5bf -[NSString substringFromIndex:] + 127
4   myApp                               0x0005896c -[AmazonServiceRequest hostName] + 188
5   myApp                               0x0001d332 -[DynamoDBRequest configureURLRequest] + 162
6   myApp                               0x0006def4 -[AmazonAbstractJsonWebServiceClient invoke:rawRequest:unmarshallerDelegate:] + 420
7   myApp                               0x0004cd6d -[AmazonDynamoDBClient describeTable:] + 157

[...]

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I guess I don't get the workflow right and do not fully understand the concept of calling to DynamoDB.

Thank's alot!

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS.  Can you share what the contents of the `ddbendpoint` variable are?  It seems the exception is occurring in trying to parse this value.

Rather than preparing this yourself, we do offer helper methods for getting a correct endpoint:

```
NSString *ddbendpoint = [AmazonEndpoints ddbEndpoint:EU_WEST_1];
```

A few more notes about your code:

```
[dtreq setRequestEndpoint:ddbendpoint]; // EU_WEST_1
[dtreq setCredentials:credentials];
```

These lines are unnecessary unless you wish to override the values already used in the client.

In the code you provided, you initialize an `AmazonDynamoDBClient` `ddb`, but then you use `[AmazonClientManager ddb]`.  Is the client initialization code actually in `AmazonClientManager` or as shown in your question?

It is important to note that while the provider will give the AmazonDynamoDBClient temporary credentials, your method of using STS does still require long term credentials to be embededded in your application (or delivered to the app). Before you deploy the app to production, I recommend you consider using web identity federation or a token vending machine to deliver credentials to your app.

Comment: Thanks, Bob! I read and followed your tutorials quite carefully. Managed to get the tokens by a TVM as well. For ddbendpoint I use this URL: [link](dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com). I rewrote the Request endpoint and credentials, because the `AmazonClientManager` sample for DynamoDB gives me a client object where the endpoint was set to standard `US_WEST_1`. Basically, I tried to follow all the AWS tutorials regarding that problem, so some code might be a bit mixed up.

Comment: Try updating the ddbendpoint variable to the one I showed in my answer, I think that's your largest issue, as the endpoint should contain the protocol as well (i.e. https://).

Comment: Hello Bob! I managed getting the data I want by following the instructions you provided here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=350559# .. My policy in the WAR-file wasn't matching the one in IAM and I had to reset my simulator. Thanks alot!